# FQL Limit clause with two numbers

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I saw some FQL queries that use a strange comma between two numbers in their `LIMIT` clause...
e.g.

```
SELECT pid, subject FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me() LIMIT 1,100
```

what does the 1st and 2nd numbers stand for? is it for pagignation ?

I know that after the `LIMIT` clause one can use an `OFFSET` to see the rest of the data and this is how i use it...

Comment: First number is offset (beginning a 0), second is row count (number of rows you want to be returned).